# Java Web Start and all-permissions

Tags: java, permissions, java-web-start

I am trying to run a simple java application via Java Web Start.  I have two different deployments.  The only difference between the two is that working version has a manifest file containing

```
Permissions: sandbox
```

and the non-working version has a manifest containing

```
Permissions: all-permissions
```

as well as a jnlp file containing

```xml
<security>
    <all-premissions/>
</security>
```

Both versions have been signed.  The non-working version gets a Application Blocked by Java Security message.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0). There is already one mistake I can see, it will likely identify others as well.

Comment: Excellent, that worked great.  Silly typo. should have been all-permissions. Works now.  Thanks Andrew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see the typo all-premissions, should have been all-permissions, until I validated the XML by referencing Andrew's XSD.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. :)